# How to distinguish online and offline sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, offline, mergesort

I have the following sorting algorithms:

```
 Bubble Sort, Selection Sort, Heap Sort, Merge Sort, Quick Sort, Insertion Sort
```

Which of them are online or offline sorts?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "online" sorting algorithm. If you're using the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm):

> In computer science, an online algorithm is one that can process its
>   input piece-by-piece in a serial fashion, i.e., in the order that the
>   input is fed to the algorithm, without having the entire input
>   available from the start.

then of the algorithms you list, only insertion sort fits the bill, because the others require that all items be in memory before sorting can begin.

With insertion sort, you're maintaining a sorted list: each item is put in its proper place as it's received. The list of items that you've received so far is always in order.

See also, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55012/what-is-the-fastest-online-sorting-algorithm

Comment: Can't heap sort also maintain a min heap while getting one element at a time?

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, you could maintain a heap. But after the last element is received, you then have to remove the items from the heap one at a time, or rearrange the heap so that the items are sorted. Either way, you have must have the all of the items in memory before you can do that, and it requires O(n log n) time to perform that step.